# Two tables cannot both align to center

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have two tables with different column number. Now I have the following code (I'm new to LaTeX, if there is a better way to have two tables in a group plz let me know).

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
     & $W_f, W_u, W_c, W_o$ & $W_y$        & $b_f, b_u, b_c, b_o$ & $b_y$      \\ \hline
Dim. & $(n_a, n_a + n_x)$   & $(n_y, n_a)$ & $(n_a, 1)$           & $(n_y, 1)$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\newline
\vspace*{0.1cm}
\newline
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
     & $a^{<t>}, a^{<t-1>}, c^{<t>}, c^{<t-1>}$ & $\Gamma_f, \Gamma_u, \Gamma_o$ & $\tilde{c}^{<t>}$ \\ \hline
Dim. & $(n_a, m)$                               & $(n_a, m)$                     & $(n_a, m)$      \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{The dimension of used parameters in an LSTM forward pass. We have a dimension size of $m$ because we are doing vectorization calculation for $m$ inputs simultaneously.}
\label{table:lstm-fp}
\end{table}
```

[image]

What I want is just let this two table vertically aligned to center. But I've failed for a while.

EDIT:

I've tried `\bigskip` but it doesn't work :(

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
        & $W_f, W_u, W_c, W_o$ & $W_y$        & $b_f, b_u, b_c, b_o$ & $b_y$      \\ \hline
Dim. & $(n_a, n_a + n_x)$   & $(n_y, n_a)$ & $(n_a, 1)$           & $(n_y, 1)$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
        & $a^{\langle t \rangle}, a^{\langle t-1 \rangle}, c^{\langle t \rangle}, c^{\langle t-1 \rangle}$ & $\Gamma_f, \Gamma_u, \Gamma_o$ & $\tilde{c}^{\langle t \rangle}$ \\ \hline
Dim. & $(n_a, m)$                               & $(n_a, m)$                     & $(n_a, m)$      \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{The dimension of used parameters in an LSTM forward pass. We have a dimension size of $m$ because we are doing vectorization calculation for $m$ inputs simultaneously.}
\label{table:lstm-fp}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Off-topic: instead of `a^{<t>}`, you may wish to write `a^{\langle t\rangle}`, etc.

Comment: Off-topic: You defined 6 columns but use only 5 ...

Comment: @Mico Thanks for telling. I actually have used `a^{\langle t\rangle}`. But I prefer to have `<>` when writing and then do replacement :DD

Comment: @ChristianHupfer woops

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest to use a common `tabular` environment for both tables and apply `\multicolumn` for the 2nd and 3rd columns in the 2nd table.

I stretched the array spacings a little bit.

Also vertical rules in tables are not recommended.

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{|*{5}{c|}}
\hline
     & $W_f, W_u, W_c, W_o$ & $W_y$        & $b_f, b_u, b_c, b_o$ & $b_y$      \\ \hline
Dim. & $(n_a, n_a + n_x)$   & $(n_y, n_a)$ & $(n_a, 1)$           & $(n_y, 1)$ \\ \hline
\multicolumn{5}{c}{} \\
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$a^{<t>}, a^{<t-1>}, c^{<t>}, c^{<t-1>}$} & $\Gamma_f, \Gamma_u, \Gamma_o$ & $\tilde{c}^{<t>}$ \\ \hline
Dim. & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$(n_a, m)$ }                              & $(n_a, m)$                     & $(n_a, m)$      \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{The dimension of used parameters in an LSTM forward pass. We have a dimension size of $m$ because we are doing vectorization calculation for $m$ inputs simultaneously.} \label{table:lstm-fp}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the solution!

Answer (score 5):

Just remove

```
\newline
\vspace*{0.1cm}
\newline
\centering
```

and insert `\bigskip` (or `\medskip`), sandwiched between blank lines,between the two `tabular` environments.

---

*Addendum*: I take it you chose to create two separate `tabular` environments so that the width of the material wouldn't exceed `\textwidth`. I think it's better to create a *single*, vertically-oriented table, and not scatter the information across two separate `tabular` environments. A separate issue: since almost all of the material is in math-mode, using an `array` environment cuts down drastically on the number of `$` symbols one has to type. I would also like to suggest that you give the table a much more "open" look by omitting all vertical lines and using just one horizontal line. Your readers will appreciate it, and they will likely reward your effort by actually studying the tabular material...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\zz}{\langle}{\rangle}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}

$\begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
\textnormal{Parameters} & \textnormal{Dimension} \\
\midrule % from 'booktabs' package
W_f, W_u, W_c, W_o & (n_a, n_a + n_x)\\
W_y & (n_y, n_a)\\
b_f, b_u, b_c, b_o & (n_a, 1)\\
b_y & (n_y, 1) \\
a^{\zz{t}}, a^{\zz{t-1}}, c^{\zz{t}}, c^{\zz{t-1}} & (n_a, m) \\
\Gamma_f, \Gamma_u, \Gamma_o & (n_a, m)\\ 
\tilde{c}^{\zz{t}} & (n_a, m) \\ 
\end{array}$

\caption{Dimensions of parameters used in an LSTM forward pass. We have a dimension size of $m$ because we are doing vectorization calculation for~$m$ inputs simultaneously.}
\label{table:lstm-fp}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: \bigskip doesn't work :( You can check the edited OP

Comment: @Kulbear: You need `\bigskip` and an empty line after that, then the 2nd `tabular`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sure, Mr. Magic

Comment: Appreciate the solution!

Comment: Sorry,  I didn't want to steal the tick (you were quicker by your proposition, so choose the `\multicolumn` approach)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - No problem at all! In the meantime, I've added a completely different solution, which uses a single, vertically-oriented `array` environment to replace the OP's two horizontally-oriented `tabular` environments.

Comment: @Mico: Yes, I saw that already. Can't upvote again, however ;-) And your 2nd solution needs more vertical space? You're a tree - killer in case the table is printed on paper :-P

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Jabba the Hutt has been called much worse than a tree-killer. :-)

Comment: @Mico: Ah, yes, your 'Alter Ego' Jabba the Hutt :D

Comment: @Mico I have worried about whether you guys care about who got the picked solution. But I see you two have a very large amount of credits I guess you won't care. I sincerely appreciate all your work as well!

Comment: @Kulbear - No worries at all. Christian H. and I have a pretty good banter going from time too time. Hopefully it's not too disturbing (or perplexing!) for folks who don't know us...

Comment: Like knows like. Oh, I just found the usage of `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`, that's a magic.